# How to find section of visible area of a big plane in current ARCamera frame?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, augmented-reality, arkit

I have a horizontal plane detection enabled in my ARKit app. I add geometry to my plane node whenever I find a new plane or get a update on existing planeAnchor. Now, I want to know what's the intersection coordinates of the partial plane which is visible in current camera frame.

Following is the code to find the nodes visible in current frame.

```
// get the current frame

if let node = sceneView.pointOfView {

    let nodes = sceneView.nodesInsideFrustum(of: node)
    print("-----")
    for node in nodes {
        print(node.name ?? "unknown node")  
    }
}
```